# How can I write the product of two transpositions as product of 3-cycles?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Consider this equality in the group $S_n$ :

$$(ab)(cd)=(cad)(abc)$$

I can prove it for myself, but I get the impression that I should be able to see this very quickly. How could I get more intuition on this ?

$$
a \overset{(abc)}{\mapsto} b \overset{(cad)}{\mapsto} b \\  
b \overset{(abc)}{\mapsto} c \overset{(cad)}{\mapsto} a \\
c \overset{(abc)}{\mapsto} a \overset{(cad)}{\mapsto} d  \\
d \overset{(abc)}{\mapsto} d \overset{(cad)}{\mapsto} c \\$$

Comment: My adivinatory skills tell me that you're talking of...cycles in the permutation group? ...

Comment: A seemingly small edit came up for approval, in which someone changed "in $S_n$" to "in a group $S_n$".  I clicked on "improve" and changed it to "in the group $S_n$", and didn't notice that the title had also been altered to one that doesn't make sense.  I suspect the comments from DonAntonio and Hurkyl are responding to the nonsensical title.  So I changed the title back to what it was originally.

Comment: @DonAntonio : Please notice my comment and consider deleting yours.

Comment: @Hurkyl : Please notice my comment and consider deleting yours.

Comment: Sorry but no, can't do Michael: I require the OP to *at least* acknowledge the editing is correct, and then I will be happy to delete my comment, as I many times (when I remember!) do...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of tracing through where it maps elements, you can also derive this from basic cycle manipulations:
$$(cad)(abc) = (dca)(cab) = (dc)(ca)(ca)(ab) = (dc)(ab)$$

The two rules I'm using are

1. $(a_1\ldots a_n) = (a_2\ldots a_na_1)$
2. $(a_1\ldots a_n) = (a_1a_2)(a_2a_3)\cdots(a_{n-1}a_n)$

Comment: thnx !! ${}{}{}{}{}{}$